# How to intercept laravel http error responses

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I am trying to handle all errors thrown by a Laravel project

I overrode some of the code in the file app\Exception\Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $err = New Response;
    $err->Response=0;
    $err->Message = $e;
    return json_encode($err);
    //return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

I commented the render function and tried to return an instance of my custom error class

However this did not work, because i am returning a different type (response does not extend ExceptionHandler

Is there a way to do what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code. does this help!

```
   public function render($request, Exception $e)
        {
               return \Response::json([
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                  ], $e->getCode());
               } 
         }
```

Comment: you mean $e->getCode() ??

Comment: @Elie $e->getcode() mean response status code like 404.

Comment: its depends on instance (object) of Exception class. if you declare Exception $exception then it should be $exception->getCode()

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor Elie is refering to the the fact that you use `$e` AND `$exception` in your code. Just change the last `$exception` to `$e` and you're good!

Comment: Thanks it still threw an error at $e->getCode(). I just replaced it with 500 :)